# Handling DisplayInformation::DisplayContentsInvalidated in D3D12

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, direct3d

In the VS2019 project template for C++/CX D3D12, the `DisplayInformation::DisplayContentsInvalidated` event (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.displaycontentsinvalidated?view=winrt-19041)) is subscribed and when this event fires, the code in the project template attempts to validate the D3D12 device. The criteria being used to validate is whether the *default* adapter has changed:

```cpp
// This method is called in the event handler for the DisplayContentsInvalidated event.
void DX::DeviceResources::ValidateDevice()
{
    // The D3D Device is no longer valid if the default adapter changed since the device
    // was created or if the device has been removed.

    // First, get the LUID for the default adapter from when the device was created.

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC previousDesc;
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> previousDefaultAdapter;
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(0, &previousDefaultAdapter));

        DX::ThrowIfFailed(previousDefaultAdapter->GetDesc(&previousDesc));
    }

    // Next, get the information for the current default adapter.

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC currentDesc;
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> currentDxgiFactory;
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&currentDxgiFactory)));

        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> currentDefaultAdapter;
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(currentDxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(0, &currentDefaultAdapter));

        DX::ThrowIfFailed(currentDefaultAdapter->GetDesc(&currentDesc));
    }

    // If the adapter LUIDs don't match, or if the device reports that it has been removed,
    // a new D3D device must be created.

    if (previousDesc.AdapterLuid.LowPart != currentDesc.AdapterLuid.LowPart ||
        previousDesc.AdapterLuid.HighPart != currentDesc.AdapterLuid.HighPart ||
        FAILED(m_d3dDevice->GetDeviceRemovedReason()))
    {
        m_deviceRemoved = true;
    }
}
```

However, it seems to me that the *default* adapter may not be the *elected* adapter, as you can see in this code, because it ensures the adapter can create a D3D12 device before electing it, and this same check does not exist in the validation code above:

```cpp
// This method acquires the first available hardware adapter that supports Direct3D 12.
// If no such adapter can be found, *ppAdapter will be set to nullptr.
void DX::DeviceResources::GetHardwareAdapter(IDXGIAdapter1** ppAdapter)
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    *ppAdapter = nullptr;

    for (UINT adapterIndex = 0; DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND != m_dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(adapterIndex, &adapter); adapterIndex++)
    {
        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc;
        adapter->GetDesc1(&desc);

        if (desc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE)
        {
            // Don't select the Basic Render Driver adapter.
            continue;
        }

        // Check to see if the adapter supports Direct3D 12, but don't create the
        // actual device yet.
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr)))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    *ppAdapter = adapter.Detach();
}
```

Is this unintentionally relying on the default adapter being the elected adapter, or are there wider assumptions we can make based on the default adapter having changed?

What is the real meaning if `DisplayInformation::DisplayContentsInvalidated`? What is this telling me? Why does this suggest the device is possibly invalid? What are the cases where this event fires andthe device would or would not be invalid?

And since we are also checking for a `DeviceRemovedReason` here, are there cases where the default adapter doesn't change but the device was removed because of `DisplayInformation::DisplayContentsInvalidated`?

Do we even really need to handle this at all? What would happen if I just completely ignored this event and kept trying to render? Would I not end up handling whatever problem this event firing is indicating in the documented "device lost scenarios" per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios)?

Comment: What does "and this same check does not exist in the validation code above" mean? Does it mean that the previousDefaultAdapter and currentDxgiFactory do not match?  Could you please provide a simple sample for us to test?

Comment: What I meant is that the validation code does not call `D3D12CreateDevice` to see if a D3D12 device can be created with the default adapter like the `GetHardwareAdapter` function does. I'm not clear on why the default device is relevant here. It's unclear what the basis of this validation is.

Comment: This simple example can be easily acquired by creating a new project in VS2019 from the `DirectX 12 App (Universal Windows C++/CX)` project template.

Answer (score 0):

We are still investigating your question and get some information.

With regards to when the DisplayContentInvalidated Event will be triggered, it is typically invoked upon various activities including changing of the primary display or if the display configurations have changed in any other way. This would also include if there were certain types of issues occurring with the graphics, which this event should be able to be utilized to handle such situations.

With regards to the template, we ran some tests on our end and we indeed did see that the project uses the first adapter that it finds that can handle DirectX12 rather than an elected adapter. Upon further tests, we removed that particular check and found that the application does indeed continue to run as expected. The adapter may not be the one that was used to create the device at application startup. So indeed, this check does seem like it can potentially be ignored as indicated. However, having this event in the code might not hurt as it can provide the extra functionality should it be required for any situation.

Any other detailed information would likely be found in our documentation regarding this. However, it seems that the template is meant for demonstrating certain functionalities of DirextX12 and its various API’s so ignoring the DisplayContentInvalidated Event should typically not cause any issues.